# How to convert first word first character to Upper case?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I want this:
Example: stackoverflow is helpful. => Stackoverflow is helpful.

As example show want to convert my first word first character to Upper Case.
I tried the code given below which not working, not understanding what I am doing wrong please help.

```html
<textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput" name="message" oninput="myFunction()" rows="10" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>

<input id="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital" onclick="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital()" style="color: black;" type="button" value="First word first character capital!" /> </br>
</br>

<script>
  function FistWordFirstCharcterCapital() {
    var x = document.getElementById("TextInput").value.replace(string[0], string[0].toUpperCase());
    document.getElementById("TextInput").value = x;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: where's the code of variable `string`?

Comment: There is not `string` variable in your code. Get the `value` to the `string` variable first and then replace: `var string = document.getElementById("TextInput").value;
var x = string.replace(string[0], string[0].toUpperCase());`

Comment: As a side note, `oninput="myFunction()"` doesn't realle make much sense, since there is no `myFunction` declaration anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make the first letter of a string uppercase in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Treat it like an array-like object to get the first character, uppercase it, then `concat` it to the rest of the string:

```js
const str = "hello World!";
const upper = ([c, ...r]) => c.toUpperCase().concat(...r);
console.log(upper(str));
```

Comment: Thanks @MaheerAli - always nice to see new answers to old questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this method

```
function jsUcfirst(string) 
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charAt` to get the first letter:

```js
const string = "stackoverflow is helpful."
const capitalizedString = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)

console.log(capitalizedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd not want to use replace, nor something like `string[0]`. Instead, use below little method

```js
const s = 'foo bar baz';

function ucFirst(str) {
  return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}

console.log(ucFirst(s));
```

Comment: Or koban's way, or one of the hundreds different solutions to that simple problem. @MaheerAli I showed one option, there are many though. Instead of yours, I'd prefer koban's though

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to beggin with JS here is a detailed example :

```js
function FistWordFirstCharcterCapital() {
  let text =  document.getElementById("TextInput").value;
  let firstSpaceIndex = text.indexOf(" ")!=-1 ? text.indexOf(" ")+1:text.length;
  let firstWord = text.substr(0, firstSpaceIndex);
  let firstWordUpper = firstWord.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + firstWord.slice(1)
  document.getElementById("TextInput").value = firstWordUpper + text.substr(firstSpaceIndex);;
}
```

```html
<textarea autocomplete="off" cols="30" id="TextInput" name="message" rows="10" style="width: 100%;">
</textarea>

<input id="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital" onclick="FistWordFirstCharcterCapital()" style="color: black;" type="button" value="First word first character capital!" />
```